# Fabric API key not valid

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to install Fabric to my iOS app. I downloaded the Fabric app to install Crashlytics but when I add the run script in build phase provided by the app, after I build the project I get the error:

> line 2: 1:myfirebaseid:ios:myfirebaseid=1:my:app:id: command not
>   found Fabric.framework/run 1.7.0 (208) error: Fabric: Configuration
>   Issue
>
> Fabric API key not valid. Your Fabric run script build phase should
>   contain your API key: ./Fabric.framework/run INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY
>   INSERT_YOUR_BUILD_SECRET

Some answers suggested removing Fabric from plist which I did and the error got away. But later, I wasn't able to complete the installation of Fabric and I think that is the reason. So where can I find my Fabric API KEY and SECRET?

Comment: As I type this, the instructions from FirebaseCrashlytics docs still don't indicate what's missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After login in **Fabric.io**, select **settings**

[image]

in that page select **Organizations**

[image]

Select your app organization

[image]

In your fabric organization page select API Key

[image]

And add that number in your info.plist

[image]

and here in your shell run script

[image]

Comment: How I get to that page? When I login in fabric.io I only have access to one page: https://fabric.io/onboard

Comment: @Student I will post more images ;)

Comment: This is not what I see when I login

Comment: post an image of what you see when you login @Student

Comment: You are  setting up your fabric account, you need to read this https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/overview.html @Student

Comment: I found this page https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install. I think here you can get the Api key and secret. Can you check it?

Comment: Yes @Student but you need to have an account and a organization

Comment: I already have. I can access the Api key and Secret from the page above. Those are the credentials I used before. So I am at point zero again.

Comment: @Student its weird because your login page seems that you don't have any organization created in your account

Answer (score 0):

I've tried @Reinier-Melian solution above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287615/3804452), it solved the error but the crashes still didn't get to the either fabric nor firebase dashboards.
I've added the old init line after initializing firebase and now it works!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

//firebase init
[FIRApp configure];
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"YOUR API KEY HERE"];
```