# Crashlytics: No settings were cached | Skipping report

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to use Crashlytics but for some reason I can't get Firebase to connect with it. I've literally tried everything and read the documentations several times.

What I did so far:

I've added it through CocoaPods

Created a new Run Script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

Added Input files:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/GoogleService-Info.plist
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

Changed from `$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` in Firebase documentation to `GoogleService-Info.plist` in XCode 10.0+, as followed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862008/1138498)

Everything on the web seems to be old and not updated to the latest Crashlytics version and this message just not want to disappear (could not get data uploaded from my device):

[image: firebase crashlytics]

I've also added `-FIRDebugEnabled` and traced logs and found that I have the following errors:

```
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.0.0-beta.5
[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone10,2, 14.0.1 (18A393)
[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Settings] No settings were cached
[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Root: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E9EFD0F4-85CF-4BB1-8E71-E5136293E004/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.xxx.xxxxxxx
[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Skipping report with id '2ff5a6c8e50c4734b89380c38cb369c0' this run of the app because Organization ID was nil. Report will upload once settings are download successfully
```

***Firebase documentation:***

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios&authuser=0
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0

Comment: it happened after iOS14 update ?

Comment: Actually I didn't used it before, that's the first time and yesterday updated to iOS 14.0

Comment: Mine took 2 days to show up in the console & running a `fatalError` on some random page to help trigger it

Comment: @HarryJ Now moving fatalError across the app to another locations, lets see what I get.